# Getting a csrf token in a form

Tags: javascript, node.js

This open source chat project https://github.com/meatspaces/meatspace-chat uses the jade index file below. You'll notice that the form has an input value for a #{csrf} token.  Where would this csrf value be coming from? Is it part of the browser environment? I don't see any javascript in the project that inserts that csrf token into that input field.

For example, when you visit the root, it just renders the index like this

```
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  });
```

index

```
extend layout

block content
  form(method='post', id='add-chat-form')
    input(type='hidden', name='picture', id='picture')
    .message-content
      input(name='message', id='add-chat', class='input', maxlength='250', autocomplete='off', placeholder='Send a public message')
      input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value='#{csrf}')
      input(type='hidden', name='fingerprint', id='fp')
      input(type='hidden', name='userid', id='userid')
      #add-chat-blocker.hidden
        span Sending, please wait!
  #counter 250
```

Comment: Most probably from connect middleware's csrf protection framework.

Comment: https://github.com/meatspaces/meatspace-chat/blob/master/settings.js#L7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens are created by the [connect csrf middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html).  You can see this in `settings.js`.  On line 7:

```
  var csrf = express.csrf();
```

and line 13:

```
  var clientBypassCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.apiKey && nativeClients.indexOf(req.body.apiKey) > -1) {
      next();
    } else {
      csrf(req, res, next);
    }
  };
```

This exposes a function `csrfToken` on the `req` object, which is used on line 45:

```
        res.locals.csrf = req.csrfToken();
```

The express templating engine (`res.render('index');` in the code you showed in your question) extends the templates scope with the `res.locals` object, which is how that field gets filled in during templating.